# how do I run multiple programs on different machines at same time?

Tags: ssh, cluster-computing

I have a 12 computers cluster and I have a java program(the same) on each one, so I want to run these programs at the same time, how can i do this?

I already can copy (`scp`) files from one computer to another via ssh like

```
#!/bin/bash
scp /route1/file1 user@computerX:/route2$
scp /route1/file1 user@computerY:/route2$
```

so I was wondering if something like this can be done to run the programs that I have on each computer

Answer (score 1):

You can run commands via

```
#!/bin/bash    
ssh user@host1 <command>
ssh user@host2 <command>
```

You will need to use Key Based Auth to avoid entering your password when the script runs.

Alternatively take a look at [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.4/) for a neat way of controlling multiple hosts.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend typing:

```
man ssh
```

and see what it says. That command will run commands remotely for you.